# Hibernate 3 / Wildfly / java8 / secondary Oracle connection without rollback

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

We are using hibernate 3.x connection pool for our main server, but for a specific request I need to make a secondary connection as SA on my oracle database. That secondary connection does not require rollback and it is used to make a call to a store procedure. Once terminated this connection could be released.

I have added a second "datasource" into my standalone.xml and so far this works.

The problem is I keep getting errors:

> ARJUNA12140: Adding multiple last resources is disallowed. Current resource is com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.abstractrecords.LastResourceRecord@

Some options I've seen is to disable transactions for the whole app, which is not suitable.

Can this be done only for the second connection?

Is there another way to establish my secondary connection with parameters still in the standalone.xml and have this secondary connection connect as a different user, execute the stored procedure and then close that connection?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just use a single data source, and use REQUIRES_NEW for the method that must be in a separate transaction.

Comment: The second connection require different credentials. Is there a way to overwrite the credentials for a transaction?

Comment: No. But since the same server must be able to open connections from the two datasources anyway, why not create a user that has all the required rights, and use a single datasource using this user?

Comment: The second user need the "admin" role as provided by AWS RDS in order to be able to create tablespace. We don't want the regular user to have this privilege. Also AWS/RDS only allow for one admin user. We have tried to add this priviledge to the regular user and we could not. We also tried to set a trigger that would act on the behalf of the Admin and that did not work.

Comment: It is possible to just use strait JDBC on my secondary connection? If so how do I configure the secondary connection with Java8 + Wildfly without interfering with hibernate 3 ?